# Magento 2.1: Only admin can upload images to visual swatch

Tags: magento-2.1, swatches, acl

Administrators can upload images to visual swatches but users with limited access can't.

I'm trying to find the resource to give this user role access to it but can't seem to figure out which one it is. Does anyone know which one it is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so i have looked into your issue further and found that that facility is not in the admin at present but if you want it to be all you need to do is create a file for it please refer to below instructions

Go to vendor/magento/module-swatches/etc/ and create file

```
acl.xml
```

And add the following code to it

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Acl/etc/acl.xsd">
    <acl>
        <resources>
            <resource id="Magento_Backend::admin">
                <resource id="Magento_Swatches::iframe" title="Swatch Upload Images" sortOrder="13" />
            </resource>
        </resources>
    </acl>
</config>
```

This is a quick fix and will be overwritten if you update. the best solution would be to create a simple module and include it under app/code

**Result**

[image]

Comment: Iv now updated my answer for you